# From dict to pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have some code to put nested json dict to dataframe.
This is not very efficient and wondering if I need to use numpy array 
for storage before creating dataframe.
Dict size is 1 million, item is a JSON string.

```
  ALL=dict()
  ALL[0]=  """{id1: 'Big_JSON' }"""
  for k_id, dd in ALL.items() :

   ii+=1 
   if ii > -1 :
    dfi=  pd.io.json.json_normalize(dd)

    if ii == 0 :
       ALL_df= dfi    
    else:
       ALL_df= pd.concat((ALL_df, dfi), axis=0)       
       print ii,
```

Is there an fast way to transform into dataframe ?

Comment: This question would likely benefit from a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, which makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using concat inefficiently, try converting all your dicts at the same time:

```
ALL_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(ALL.values())
```

Comment: What about the key needed for columns since all the json files have different keys.... (sometimes, key can be missing... for one row).